# Uniform adjustment

Tags: javascript, css

So im trying to figure out how I could make all of my webpage change size when you zoom in or out at the same proportion. I cant figure out how to do this but here is a little test Fiddle I created in a couple minutes.

https://jsfiddle.net/cejnkx4h/1/

So as you can see in this, whenever the browser/canvas changes size all the text and stuff changes proportion. I want the user to be able to zoom in to accommodate impairments however I want the entire webpage to zoom in at the same proportion, not just certain elements like the text.
If any of you guys can help me I'd appreciate it a lot.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("https://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/blur_colors-wide.jpg");
  background-position: cover;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-width: 1000px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bg {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  background-color: grey;
  border: thick solid black;
  height: 100%;
}

#right {
  width: 45%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border: thick solid black;
}

#left {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16pt;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.format {
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="format">
    <div id="left">
      <p>
        Gaming Pc
        <br/>$1500
      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <img src="https://www.cyberpowerpc.com/images/cs/smraidmax/blk_400.png" width="100%" </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47762493/website-zooming-in

Answer (score 1):

You can use css transform to scale the page proportionally.

```
transform: scale(1);
```

Something like this. Where scale 1 means a 100%. You can set it to something like 0.5 for 50% or 1.1 for 110%.

Hope this helps.